# Schreibt man „gut stehen“ oder „gutstehen“, wenn es um Chancen geht?

Tags: verb, spelling, compound

Ich bin mir bei diesem Satz nicht sicher, wie man ihn schreibt:

> Darum besteht die Möglichkeit, dass die Chance für Neues **gut steht**.

oder

> Darum besteht die Möglichkeit, dass die Chance für Neues **gutsteht**.

Ich hätte es aus dem Bauch heraus getrennt geschrieben.

Was ist richtig und wieso?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Getrennt schreiben ist hier richtig. Das Verb *gutstehen* (zusammen geschrieben) gibt es zwar, hat aber eine andere Bedeutung.

Davon abgesehen, ist im gegebenen Satz *dass* mit doppeltem s und Komma davor zu schreiben (edit: das wurde inzwischen behoben).

Ich könnte mir außerdem vorstellen, dass man den Satz auch ganz grundsätzlich besser formulieren könnte, denn mit *Es besteht die Möglichkeit* und *Die Chance steht gut* beinhaltet der kurze Satz gleich zwei Instanzen gewisser Wahrscheinlichkeiten.

Edit 2:
Wie von Raketenolli angemerkt, ist der Ausdruck *Die Chancen stehen gut* im Plural deutlich gebräuchlicher als die Form *Die Chance steht gut*.

Comment: *Die Chance steht gut* habe ich vorher noch nie gehört, ich kenne den Ausdruck nur im Plural: *Die Chancen stehen gut*. Duden.de hat auch nur ein Beispiel im Plural.

Comment: @Raketenolli das war mir gar nicht aufgefallen. Darum ging es zwar in der Frage nicht, aber es stimmt, *Die Chancen stehen gut* ist viel gebräuchlicher als die Singularform, die aber zumindest auch von diversen Büchern und Zeitschriften verwendet wird (das behauptet jedenfalls Google).

Comment: ja, es ist leicht off topic, aber ich wollte vermeiden dass interessierte Leser sich hier falsche oder zumindest wenig verbreitete und deswegen schlechter verständliche Ausdrücke angewöhnen.

Comment: I would add in the answer what @Raketenolli said.

Answer (score 1):

Maßgeblich ist der § 34 der [amtlichen Rechtschreibregeln](http://www.rechtschreibrat.com/DOX/rfdr_regeln-woerterverzeichnis_inkl_Nachtraegen.pdf):

> § 34: Partikeln, Adjektive, Substantive oder Verben können als Verbzusatz mit Verben trennbare Zusammensetzungen bilden. Man schreibt sie nur in den Infinitiven, den Partizipien sowie im Nebensatz bei Endstellung des Verbs zusammen.

Eingeworfen werden muss an dieser Stelle, dass es sich keinesfalls um eine untrennbare Zusammensetzung im Sinne des § 33 handelt. Das lässt sich leicht erkennen, indem man einen Hauptsatz bildet, in dem es heißt:

> Die Chance steht gut.

Da hier Adjektiv und Verb *nicht mehr* gemeinsam an einer Stelle stehen (»*Die Chance gutsteht«) kann keine untrennbare Zusammensetzung vorliegen. Es ist nur noch festzustellen, ob eine trennbare Zusammensetzung vorliegt, die Zusammenschreiben erfordert, oder nicht (woraus sich Getrenntschreibung ergibt).

Dazu heißt es im Paragraphen weiter:

> Dies betrifft:
>
> […]
>
> 2. Zusammensetzungen mit einem adjektivischen ersten Bestandteil.
>
>    Dabei sind folgende Fälle zu unterscheiden:
>
>    1. Es kann zusammen- wie auch getrennt geschrieben werden, wenn
>         ein einfaches Adjektiv eine Eigenschaft als Resultat des Verbalvorgangs
>         bezeichnet (sog. resultative Prädikative), zum Beispiel:
>         *blank putzen/blankputzen, glatt hobeln/glatthobeln, klein schneiden/
>         kleinschneiden; kalt stellen/kaltstellen, kaputt machen/kaputtmachen,
>         leer essen/leeressen*
>    2. Es wird zusammengeschrieben, wenn der adjektivische Bestandteil
>         zusammen mit dem verbalen Bestandteil eine neue, idiomatisierte
>         Gesamtbedeutung bildet, die nicht auf der Basis der Bedeutungen der
>         einzelnen Teile bestimmt werden kann, zum Beispiel:
>         *krankschreiben, freisprechen, (sich) kranklachen; festnageln* (= festlegen),
>         *heimlichtun* (= geheimnisvoll tun), *kaltstellen* (= [politisch] ausschalten),
>         *kürzertreten* (= sich einschränken), *richtigstellen* (= berichtigen),
>         *schwerfallen* (= Mühe verursachen), *heiligsprechen*
>
>    E5: Lässt sich in einzelnen Fällen keine klare Entscheidung darüber treffen, ob eine idiomatisierte Gesamtbedeutung vorliegt, so bleibt es dem Schreibenden überlassen, getrennt oder zusammenzuschreiben.
>
>    3. In den anderen Fällen wird getrennt geschrieben. Dazu zählen
>         insbesondere Verbindungen mit morphologisch komplexen oder erweiterten
>         Adjektiven, zum Beispiel:
>         *bewusstlos schlagen, ultramarinblau streichen, ganz nahe kommen,
>         dingfest machen, schachmatt setzen*

(Formatierung an Markdown angepasst)

Eine idiomatisierte Gesamtbedeutung wie in Abschnitt (2.2) liegt auf keinen Fall vor, denn dass die Chance gut steht, bedeutet nichts anderes, als dass eine gute Chance vorliegt. *Gut stehen* oder *gutstehen* bezeichnet hier auch nicht das Resultat eines Vorgangs wie nach (2.1). Folglich greift (2.3) und die beiden Satzglieder werden getrennt geschrieben.

Das ist auch ziemlich logisch, wenn man sich überlegt, dass *gut* und *stehen* nur sehr schwach miteinander verbunden sind. Es braucht schon irgendeine tiefergehende Gemeinsamkeit, um Zusammenschreibung auszulösen. Dagegen wird in der Regel getrennt geschreiben, wenn das Adjektiv problemlos austauschbar ist, wie hier:

> Die Chance steht schlecht.
>
> Die Chance steht bescheiden.
>
> Die Chance steht heute besser als gestern.

Diese Sätze sind in keiner Weise besonders, während das bei folgender Abwandlung des amtlichen Beispiels *kranklachen* schon anders aussieht:

> Er lacht sich gesund.

Es ist zwar verständlich, aber nur indem man sich den Umweg über *kranklachen* klarmacht.